# Google Tag manager issue classname ends with '-ok'

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager to track some clicks in my search engine.
My search engine shows books, with their cover, title, author etcetera.
When a book is available it shows a checkmark and 'Leverbaar' (In stock) text underneath the price div (17,90).

[image]
I have a Tag, with track type: Event.
That Tag has the following triggers:
Trigger when on specific page,

```
Trigger on all Elements, Some Clicks:
Click Element Matches CSS Selector :
.zoekresultaat-cover, .zoekresultaat-titel, .zoekresultaat-auteur, .zoekresultaat-ondertitel, .zoekresultaat-leverbaar-ok, .zoekresultaat-leverbaar-nok
```

HTML

```
<div class="cb-Artikel-row cb-meerdere-Titels">
    <div class="cb-col1">
        <figure class="artikel-cover">
            <div class="cb-Titeldetails">
                <img src="https://cbonline.boekhuis.nl/thumbnails/2552/9789463332552_covrtn.jpg" class="cb-Titeldetails zoekresultaat-cover">
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>

    <div class="cb-col2">
        <div class="zoekresultaat-auteur"></div>
        <div class="zoekresultaat-titel">Hallo! Kraambezoek</div>
        <div class="zoekresultaat-reeks">Hello Baby</div>
        <div class="cb-Titeldetails-artikelgegevens">
            <div class="zoekresultaat-bindwijze">Hardcover</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cb-Titeldetails-titelgegevens">
            <span class="taal zoekresultaat-taal">Nederlands</span>
            <span class="verdeler">|</span>
            <span class="verschijningsdatum zoekresultaat-verschijningsdatum">2018</span>
            <span class="verdeler">|</span>
            <span class="ISBN zoekresultaat-isbn">9789463332552</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cb-col3">
        <div class="cb-col3-Wrapper">
            <div class="cb-Prijs-En-Leverbaarheid">
                <div class="cb-Titeldetails-prijs zoekresultaat-prijs">13,95</div>
                <div class="cb-Titeldetails-boeksoort zoekresultaat-boeksoort"> (Algemeen)</div>
                <div class="cb-BeschikbaarheidMelding">
                <div class="cb-Titeldetails-leverbaar-ok zoekresultaat-leverbaar-ok">Leverbaar</div>
                <div><span style="color:black" class="CBIcon-CBO-095-pijltje_verder" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
                <div class="cb-Titeldetails-assortiment zoekresultaat-assortimenttype">CB-assortiment</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Event Label is a Custom Javascript variable with the following code:

```
function(){
 // zoekresultaat
 //// cover  <-- click on cover.
 if({{Click Classes}}.indexOf('zoekresultaat-cover') >= 0){
   var ISBN = {{Click ID}};
   ISBN = ISBN.replace('titel_img_','');
   return 'cover || ISBN:' + ISBN;
 }
 // all other click classes.indexOf which are working well..
 }
 // price
 if({{Click Classes}}.indexOf('zoekresultaat-prijs') >= 0){
   var ISBN = $({{Click Element}}).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.zoekresultaat-isbn').text();
   return 'prijs || ISBN:' + ISBN; ;
 }
 // In stock  <-- Click on in stock: available
 if({{Click Element}}.indexOf('zoekresultaat-leverbaar-ok') >= 0){
   var ISBN = $({{Click Element}}).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.zoekresultaat-isbn').text();
   return 'Leverstatus: Leverbaar || ISBN:' + ISBN; 
 }
 // Not in stock <-- Click on in stock: not available
 if({{Click Classes}}.indexOf('zoekresultaat-leverbaar-nok') >= 0){
   var ISBN = $({{Click Element}}).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.zoekresultaat-isbn').text();
   return 'Leverstatus: Niet leverbaar || ISBN:' + ISBN; 
 }

 // other elements
 else{
   return 'Onbekend'; // unknown element has been clicked.
 }
}
```

When I activate the preview mode in Google Tag Manager to test out my Tag. It's all working fine on div elements like author, cover, price and title.

The only objects that do not give the right results back are the stock status divs: .zoekresultaat-leverbaar-ok and .zoekresultaat-leverbaar-nok :

Aparrently Tag Manager thinks that I'm clicking on the cover img, which I'm not...
[image]
[image]

**Inspecting elements in Chrome**
[image]
[image]

The .cb-col1, .cb-col2, .cb-col3  div has the CSS: display:inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Google Tag Manager has issues with classes ending at:
'-ok'.

I was testing out if it might be the amount of '-' inside a classname.
When I was testing 'cb-Titeldetails-leverbaar-o' it was recognized by Tag Manager when I clicked the div. After that I've tried 'cb-Titeldetails-leverbaar-ok'  and it failed.

So my third test was 'cb-Titeldetails-leverbaar-oke', this one was also recognized by Tag Manager, so my conclusion is that Tag Manager has issues with classes ending at '-ok'.

I've changed the class to cb-Titeldetails-leverbaar-Y.